# How can I edit/change an existing customer's email address?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce3

In Craft Commerce (v3), we have a number of orders of customers with a typo in their email address. I'd like to correct those email addresses in Craft, so I went to `commerce -> customers`. However, I can't seem to find a way to change an existing customer's email address.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Isn't this a user setting? I think you can edit this in "Users".

Comment: As most customers are not users, this is not the solution.

Comment: You are right...sry